# Is it possible to generate a `yarn.lock` file without installing the packages?

Tags: javascript, yarnpkg

I need to generate a `yarn.lock` file from my `package.json` but I want to avoid `node_modules` creation. Is it possible?

Comment: How do you know your yarn.lock works...

Comment: Why do you need to avoid creating `node_modules`?

Comment: I need the same and the reason is that I am in a metered connection, so downloading 1GB in my local machine ATM is not feasible but Heroku can/should install it all without problem.

Comment: Another use case: we do some linting on package.json / yarn.lock in our CI

Comment: one more reason: resolving conflicts in `yarn.lock` file

Answer (score 18):

**EDIT**: Please check the comment below for a solution without the need for any additional package thanks to @talon55 : `npm install --package-lock-only; yarn import`

**Old answer**:

This is actually one of the few features that NPM has (`npm install --package-lock-only`) and Yarn does not support.

It is a heavily requested feature as you can tell from these 2 open Github issues: [5738](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/5738) and [2340](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/2340)

I stumbled upon the command `yarn generate-lock-entry` documented in [here](https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/cli/generate-lock-entry/) but it definitely does not do what we are looking for.

The workaround I would suggest is generating an NPM lock file and converting it to a `yarn.lock` file using [synp](https://github.com/imsnif/synp):

```sh
npm install -g synp
npm install --package-lock-only
synp --source-file package-lock.json
```

Please note that Synp requires the the packages to be installed and that the node_modules is rightly populated. This may, or may not be, a problem to your use case.

Comment: It turns out that Yarn natively supports importing package-lock.json files. So you could do this without synp as follows:
`npm install --package-lock-only; yarn import`

Comment: Try out the new `yarn install --mode update-lockfile`. https://github.com/yarnpkg/berry/pull/2913

Answer (score 16):

Available since yarn v3.0.0-rc.10

```
yarn install --mode update-lockfile
```

Comment: for pnpm users: `pnpm i --lockfile-only`

Answer (score -2):

```
yarn generate-lock-entry > yarn.lock
```