# Is there a way to force npm to generate package-lock.json?

Tags: node.js, npm, package-lock.json

I deleted it by accident and have made many changes to `package.json` since. An `npm install` or `npm update` do not generate `package-lock.json` anymore. I tried clearing my npm cache and my nvm cache, but nothing seems to be working. I tried it on several versions of Node.js (6.10.3 Node.js - 3.10.10 npm is what I would like it to work on), and it doesn't work on any.

Is there a way to force npm to generate the `package-lock.json` file?

Comment: I think package-lock.json is specific to npm 5

Comment: `package-lock.json` is generating automatically by default in npm starting from v5, in the previous versions, the lock file name was `npm-shrinkwrap.json` and it was generated manually using `npm shrinkwrap` command.

Comment: @BrettMerrifield Thank you! That was my problem. I updated to `node 8.6.0` and with it `npm 5.3.0` and it worked.

Comment: **Check your `.gitignore`.** I accidentally had `package-lock.json` in the `.gitignore` somehow and because `package-lock.json` wasn't showing up in the `git status` it was throwing me off.

Comment: How do we achieve this with YARN ?

Comment: `yarn install --mode update-lockfile` for yarn, `pnpm i --lockfile-only`for pnpm,  via https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44438303/is-it-possible-to-generate-a-yarn-lock-file-without-installing-the-packages

Answer (score 613, accepted):

In npm 6.x and 7.x you can use

```
npm i --package-lock-only
```

According to the docs of [npm v6](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/commands/npm-install), [npm v7](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/commands/npm-install) or [latest version](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install.html):

> The --package-lock-only argument will only update the package-lock.json, instead of checking node_modules and downloading dependencies.

Comment: This is the correct answer now, others are old and wont work.

Comment: Any clue how to generate a package-lock.json without devDependencies?  I need this for clean production installs.  `npm i --package-lock-only --only=production` doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to generate `package-lock.json` only for production dependencies. But if you run `npm i --only=production` it should install only production dependencies. 

So your build process could look like this: install all dependencies, build app, remove `node_modules` and install only production dependencies.

Comment: This is very helpful if you want to move an older project away from yarn.lock. Thank you.

Comment: Be sure you run the command listed in the answer and not `npm i package-lock-only` without the two dashes or you'll install a package named "package-lock-only."  Guess how I found out?

Comment: This resolves a pretty frustrating issue when updating the import of private GH repos via SSH

Answer (score 245):

By default, `package-lock.json` is updated whenever you run `npm install`. However, this can be disabled globally by setting `package-lock=false` in `~/.npmrc`.

When the global `package-lock=false` setting is active, you can still force a project’s `package-lock.json` file to be updated by running:

```
npm install --package-lock
```

This command is the only surefire way of forcing a `package-lock.json` update.

Comment: @RonNewcomb Can you share more information? What do you mean by "it doesn't work"? Which npm version are you using?

Comment: npm version 3.10.10  Node 6.10.3   The command you listed seems to be a no-op?  Nothing happens. No error, no file change, nothing.

Comment: If you're using npm v3 for your project, you wouldn't have a `package-lock.json`. `package-lock.json` is only supported by npm v5+.

Comment: npm v 6.4.1 and this does not create package-lock.json

Comment: This used to not work for me (I have package-lock=false) but with npm v 6.5.0 it started properly generating the package-lock.json file.

Comment: It works for me, in 6.4.1. Setting it to false also prevents it from creating one.

Comment: npm 6.14.5 updates `package-lock.json` by `npm install` as expected.

Answer (score 18):

This is answered in the comments; `package-lock.json` is a feature in `npm` v5 and higher. `npm shrinkwrap` is how you create a lockfile in all versions of `npm`.

Comment: note, however, that `package-lock.json`s are not the exact same thing as shrinkwrap files.

Comment: in npm 5+, they are, in fact, exactly the same, down to every detail, except for one thing: `npm-shrinkwrap.json` will be published to the registry, and `package-lock.json` will not.

Comment: Yep. That's a pretty important difference though, which is why I left my comment.

Comment: `npm shrinkwrap` generates `npm-shrinkwrap.json`, but how do you generate `package-lock.json` ?

Comment: It’s automatic in npm 5+, or you can force it in 5+ with `--package-lock`

Comment: @Vic Just rename npm-shrinkwrap.json to package-lock.json. They have the same format.

Answer (score 4):

If you're like me, you tried all the answers here and wondered why no `package-lock.json` was appearing in your Git "Changed Files". In this case, check to make sure nobody has added `package-lock.json` to the `.gitignore` in the past!

Not really a direct answer, but maybe it will help someone else who spent entirely too long on this

Answer (score 2):

As several answer explained the you should run:

**`npm i`**

**BUT** if it does *not* solve...

**Check the version of your `npm` executable.** (For me it was 3.x.x which doesn't uses the `package-lock.json` (at all))

`npm -v`

It should be **at least 5.x.x** (which [introduced](https://blog.pusher.com/what-you-need-know-npm-5/) the package-lock.json file.)

To update `npm` on Linux, follow [these](https://www.hostingadvice.com/how-to/update-node-js-latest-version/) instructions.

For more details about package files, please read [this medium](https://medium.com/coinmonks/everything-you-wanted-to-know-about-package-lock-json-b81911aa8ab8) story.

Answer (score 0):

When working with local packages, the only way I found to reliably regenerate the package-lock.json file is to delete it, as well as in the linked modules and all corresponding node_modules folders and let it be regenerated with `npm i`

Answer (score -1):

If your **npm** version is **lower** than **version 5** then install the higher version for getting the automatic generation of **package-lock.json**.

**Example:** Upgrade your current **npm** to the version 6.14.0 (example - You can choose any other latest version)

```
npm i -g npm@6.14.0
```

You could view the latest **npm** version list by

```
npm view npm versions
```