# Build failed: npm ERR! Missing a lot of unknown packages

Tags: node.js, firebase, npm, google-cloud-functions

I initialized a new firebase project in my project. I added functions to my project and I am trying to deploy the default helloWorld function.

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");

// // Create and deploy your first functions
// // https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started
//
exports.helloWorld = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  functions.logger.info("Hello logs!", {structuredData: true});
  response.send("Hello from Firebase!");
});
```

When I do this I get the following error saying it is missing a lot of packages I have never heard of.

```
i  functions: updating Node.js 16 function helloWorld(us-central1)...
Build failed: ...c-fn@2.1.0 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: error-ex@1.3.2 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: json-parse-even-better-errors@2.3.1 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: lines-and-columns@1.2.4 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: is-arrayish@0.2.1 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: find-up@4.1.0 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: ansi-styles@5.2.0 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: react-is@18.2.0 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: kleur@3.0.3 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: sisteransi@1.0.5 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: is-core-module@2.11.0 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: path-parse@1.0.7 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: supports-preserve-symlinks-flag@1.0.0 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: resolve-from@5.0.0 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: buffer-from@1.1.2 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: escape-string-regexp@2.0.0 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: char-regex@1.0.2 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: glob@7.2.3 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: is-number@7.0.0 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: picocolors@1.0.0 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: convert-source-map@1.9.0 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: makeerror@1.0.12 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: tmpl@1.0.5 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: yallist@3.1.1 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: ansi-styles@3.2.1 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: escape-string-regexp@1.0.5 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: supports-color@5.5.0 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: color-convert@1.9.3 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: color-name@1.1.3 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: has-flag@3.0.0 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: locate-path@5.0.0 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: argparse@1.0.10 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: sprintf-js@1.0.3 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: p-locate@4.1.0 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: p-limit@2.3.0 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: p-try@2.2.0 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: cliui@8.0.1 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: yargs-parser@21.1.1 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: locate-path@5.0.0 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: p-locate@4.1.0 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: p-limit@2.3.0 from lock file
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Clean install a project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Usage:
npm ERR! npm ci
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Options:
npm ERR! [-S|--save|--no-save|--save-prod|--save-dev|--save-optional|--save-peer|--save-bundle]
npm ERR! [-E|--save-exact] [-g|--global] [--global-style] [--legacy-bundling]
npm ERR! [--omit <dev|optional|peer> [--omit <dev|optional|peer> ...]]
npm ERR! [--strict-peer-deps] [--no-package-lock] [--foreground-scripts]
npm ERR! [--ignore-scripts] [--no-audit] [--no-bin-links] [--no-fund] [--dry-run]
npm ERR! [-w|--workspace <workspace-name> [-w|--workspace <workspace-name> ...]]
npm ERR! [-ws|--workspaces] [--include-workspace-root] [--install-links]
npm ERR!
npm ERR! aliases: clean-install, ic, install-clean, isntall-clean
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Run "npm help ci" for more info

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /www-data-home/.npm/_logs/2023-02-28T21_49_46_615Z-debug-0.log; Error ID: beaf8772

Functions deploy had errors with the following functions:
    helloWorld(us-central1)
```

I installed the firebase-functions package, also let firebase install it's packages in the setup when initializing.
I tried removing node_modules, remove cache, remove lock, reinstalling.
I tried removing firebase from my project and reinitializing it.
I tried changing my Node version.

I am really clueless.

Hope someone can help me!

Thanks!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

FIXED! I fixed this by removing the lockfile after installing the packages and then deploy to firebase without lockfile.

Comment: I have no idea, why this works... but kudos man 

Comment: Looks like Google/Firebase keeps using the lockfile that it already has or generates its own. Until we push no lockfile, then it wil overwrite it with the new packages. You’ll be fine if you just exclude the lock from your deployment!

Comment: Oh, I can't upvote this answer that's strange... Oh yea right, I forgot about this.

Comment: In theory, the lockfile is serving a worthwhile purpose.  It's probably healthier to regenerate it- rename the old one to .old or something and then run `npm install` from within your functions directory- than to delete it outright.  The underlying issue might be some corruption of the lockfile; my regenerated file was twice as large as the one I had when I got this error.

Comment: @LaurensSmid could you please elaborate a little bit, what is lockfile in here? I am sorry, I am a beginner in Node JS. do you mean package-lock.json file?

Comment: ahh you are correct, I can deploy to firebase after deleting package-lock.json file. thank you very much!

Comment: Wow, I wasted a day solving it, regenerating lock file, asking firebase support (btw. they didn't have the solution), and this simple hack worked! Thanks!

Comment: One hour of looking for solutions and this is only one which works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Another fix! You can also use this command while in your functions directory:

```
npm i --package-lock-only
```

This updates the package-lock.json according to the docs of [npm v6](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/commands/npm-install), [npm v7](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/commands/npm-install), or the [latest version](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install.html).

Read more here -  [Is there a way to force npm to generate package-lock.json?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46653833/is-there-a-way-to-force-npm-to-generate-package-lock-json)

Answer (score 0):

Adding my 2 cent here, might help somebody desperately looking for a solution: I cd'ed in the function directory and updated firebase cloud functions:

```
npm i --save firebase-functions@latest
```

Answer (score -1):

I know you have already found a solution, I have came across a similar issue, my problem was that I was in the wrong directory, to deploy function I believe you need to be within the functions directory of the firebase project.

Comment: Firebase knows to look for the functions folder, you should be able to deploy in from root.