# Generating package-lock.json gives npm ERR! Cannot convert undefined or null to object

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, package.json, package-lock.json

The `package-lock.json` of an existing project has been deleted for whatever reason.

Trying to recreate it gives the following error

```
$ npm i --package-lock-only
npm ERR! Cannot convert undefined or null to object

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\onthe\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-05-25T14_48_07_317Z-debug-0.log
```

In the log file I can see the following

```
2843 verbose stack TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
2843 verbose stack     at Function.keys (<anonymous>)
2843 verbose stack     at module.exports (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-pick-manifest\lib\index.js:213:22)
2843 verbose stack     at RegistryFetcher.manifest (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\pacote\lib\registry.js:119:22)
2843 verbose stack     at async Promise.all (index 10)
2843 verbose stack     at async [buildDepStep] (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\arborist\lib\arborist\build-ideal-tree.js:1044:5)
2843 verbose stack     at async Arborist.buildIdealTree (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\arborist\lib\arborist\build-ideal-tree.js:207:7)
2843 verbose stack     at async Arborist.reify (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\arborist\lib\arborist\reify.js:159:5)
2843 verbose stack     at async Install.exec (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\commands\install.js:147:5)
2843 verbose stack     at async module.exports (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\cli.js:89:5)

$ node --version
v18.16.0

$ npm --version
9.6.5
```

The same error occurrs if I just do `npm install`

Comment: Does `npm ci` generate a correct package-lock or do you not want to run this?

Comment: @CodyＧ I can use any command as long as my work gets done. I got `npm i --package-lock-only` from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46653833/is-there-a-way-to-force-npm-to-generate-package-lock-json
`npm ci` gives the following error `npm ERR! The 'npm ci' command can only install with an existing package-lock.json or npm ERR! npm-shrinkwrap.json with lockfileVersion >= 1.`

Comment: do you have a `npm-shrinkwrap.json` file? If so delete it and try `npm ci` again

Comment: @CodyＧ nope, no `npm-shrinkwrap.json`

Comment: Eh. Can you share your `package.json` in the question?  Have you tried putting the `package.json` in a NEW directory by itself and running `npm i` ?

Comment: @CodyＧ Tried putting `package.json` in a new folder and running `npm i` from within that folder. I get the same error. Just saw while googling that this error might occur if there is a package in `package.json` that doesn't exist anymore. Not sure how do I find out which package doesn't exist.

Comment: You can just search each package name on npmjs.com. But yeah installing each package manually is a next good step